# Plot black and white mandelbrot set

Tags: matlab, plot, mandelbrot, imshow

Below code is taken from [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.m).

I am trying to make following change to the code below

> If c is not part of the set, plot a white
>   pixel, and if it is part of the set, plot a black pixel.

I am getting this output:
[image]

But I want to plot a black and white mandelbrot image like this:

[image]

> Use the imshow command to plot your image

Can anyone help ?

```
    m=601; 
    n=401;
    count_max = 200;

  %Change the range of x's and y's here 
  x_max =   1;
  x_min = - 2;
  y_max =   1;
  y_min = - 1;

%
%  Create an array of complex sample points in [x_min,x_max] + [y_min,y_max]*i.
%
  I = ( 1 : m );
  J = ( 1 : n );
  X = ( ( I - 1 ) * x_max + ( m - I ) * x_min ) / ( m - 1 );
  Y = ( ( J - 1 ) * y_max + ( n - J ) * y_min ) / ( n - 1 );
  [ Zr, Zi ] = meshgrid ( X, Y );
  C = complex ( Zr, Zi );
%
%  Carry out the iteration.
%
  epsilon = 0.001;

  Z = C;
  ieps = 1 : numel ( C );

  %Iterate through 1 to maximum no. of iterations
  for i = 1 : count_max
    Z(ieps) = Z(ieps) .* Z(ieps) + C(ieps); 
    W(ieps) = exp ( - abs ( Z(ieps) ) );
    ieps = ieps ( find ( epsilon < W(ieps) ) );
  end
%
%  Display the data.
%
  d = log ( abs ( Z ) );
  t = delaunay ( Zr, Zi );
%
%  To see individual pixels, use 'flat' color.
%
 h = trisurf ( t, Zr, Zi, d, 'FaceColor', 'flat', 'EdgeColor', 'flat' );
%  h = trisurf ( t, Zr, Zi, d, 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'EdgeColor', 'interp' );

  view ( 2 )
  axis equal
  axis on
  title_string = sprintf ( 'Mandelbrot set, %d x %d pixels, %d iterations', ...
    m, n, count_max );
  title ( title_string )
  xlabel ('Real Axis');
  ylabel ('Imaginary Axis');
%  Terminate.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference of belonging to the set and not belonging to the set is nothing else than `epsilon < W(ieps)` and you are already using that in your code. The colorinformation in the plot is coming from the fourth argument of `trisurf ( t, Zr, Zi, d,...)`.

So I suggest to do the following before the `trisurf` command:

```
d(1 : numel ( C )) = 1;
d(ieps) = 0;
```

This first sets all elements to 1 and then sets those elements to zero that are part of the set, according to the condition that was already calculated in the last iteration of the convergence test.

To plot black and white, just use `colormap gray` after the `trisurf`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes it works thanks can you tell me how can I view the image using `imshow` command instead of `view(2)` ?

Comment: When I do this `imshow(h)` I get a 3D view along with some error message in the command window when I am interested in only 2D.

Comment: @newguy Why do you want to use `imshow` over the standard figure? I think you would need to process the three dimensional data into a two-dimensional image first, in order to use `imshow()`.

Comment: Its a requirement hence I have to complete it.